# vue-router перехватывает запросы

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Что-то понять не могу никак, возможно кто-то подскажет. 
Настроил vue-router но вызываю action на запрос с локально файла данных, и он мне выдает 404 страницу.

Все вроде по мануалу `.htaccess` как рекомендуют на сайте:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Но по ссылке ни на `localhost:8080/файл.html или файл.php` выдает 404 от `vue-router`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, во время работы `npm run dev` проект не может сослаться на себя, в этом и проблема была. После билда проекта и заливки в отдельную папку все заработало.

Comment: Удалите вопрос или оформите грамотно ответ и поставьте галочку, И текст вопроса поправьте, чтобы вопрос был полезен другим пользователям